# How can I have images that are side-by-side and have numbers attached to each one?

Tags: floats, horizontal-alignment, subfloats, subcaption

For example:

```
*Image 1* *Image 2* *Image 3*
   (i)       (ii)     (iii)
 Figure n. Multiple images. (i) image at time n. (ii) Image at time n+1. (iii) Image at time n+2
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I use `subfigure` for this. Here's a [blog post](http://texblog.wordpress.com/2007/08/28/placing-figurestables-side-by-side-subfigure/) that describes its usage. In summary (taken from the post),

```
\begin{figure}
 \subfigure[Caption of subfigure 1]{
  % content of subfigure 1
  \label{fig:subfig1}
 }
 % repeat subfigure as necessary
 \label{fig:labelForFullFigure}
 \caption{Caption of subfigures \subref{fig:subfig1}, \subref{fig:subfig2} and \subref{fig:subfig3}}
\end{figure}
```

An alternative would be [`subfig`](ftp://ctan.tug.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/subfig/subfig.pdf). The documentation on CTAN (linked) shows its usage.

Answer (score 10):

There are several packages available to achieve that:

- `subcaption`, belonging to the very good caption package
- `subfig`
- `subfigure`, older than subfig and some consider it as obsolete

Here's an example using `subcaption`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\renewcommand\thesubfigure{\roman{subfigure}}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{minipage}[b]{.3\linewidth}
\centering%
\includegraphics[width=100pt]{test}
\subcaption{First image}\label{fig:1a}
\end{minipage}%
\hfill%
\begin{minipage}[b]{.3\linewidth}
\centering%
\includegraphics[width=100pt]{test}
\subcaption{Second image}\label{fig:1b}
\end{minipage}
\hfill%
\begin{minipage}[b]{.3\linewidth}
\centering%
\includegraphics[width=100pt]{test}
\subcaption{Third image}\label{fig:1b}
\end{minipage}
\caption{Multiple images}\label{fig:1}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]